# Sharepoint XSL - break string into componant parts

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, xslt

I'm using a "choice" site column with the multiple-check option enabled so that users can tag a list item with several choices from the column.

This column then powers a design feature in a content query webpart - where the column choice is appended to create an image filename.

- Choice1
- Choice2
- Choice3
- Choice4

becomes

```
<img src="http://mysite/content-Choice1.jpg />
```

The problem I've got is that the XSL parser is fed a string which has semicolons (;) and hashes (#) separating the choice values. If all 4 options were ticked, the string fed into the XSLT parser would be:

```
;#Choice1;#Choice2;#Choice3;#Choice4
```

How can I work through the string and separate each choice into its own XSL variable?

I've tried various substring-before functions, but I can't get anything working.

Comment: General `xslt` questions should have input source, desired output and relationship. This question is for an specific XSLT framework. As general XSLT question the answer is there is no way for `How can I work through the string and separate each choice into it's own XSL variable?`. You could built a temporaly result tree (with extensions functions for XSLT 1.0) holding a elements for each "Choice" string. See questions about tokenizing in XSLT.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to use JavaScript to parse the string and accordingly display the image using JavaScript.

Comment: Hiya - the XSL is parsed in MOSS before it hits the page, so I'd prefer a server-side XSLT solution to post-processing on page.

Comment: Go with the frederic reply then :)

Comment: You can have [embedded javascript in the XSL](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt11/#ecmascript-binding)

Answer (score 2):

Since XPath 1.0 does not support the `tokenize()` function, you'll have to do all the work yourself. For instance, you can generate the `<img>` elements recursively from the choices:

```
<xsl:template name="RecurseConvertChoicesToImages">
    <xsl:param name="choices" />

    <xsl:variable name="token"
        select="substring-before($choices, ';#')" />
    <xsl:variable name="nextToken"
        select="substring-after($choices, ';#')" />

    <xsl:if test="$token">
        <img src="http://mysite/content-{$token}.jpg" />
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="$nextToken">
        <xsl:call-template name="RecurseConvertChoicesToImages">
            <xsl:with-param name="choices" select="$nextToken" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: @Ashutosh Singh, if you like the answer, click "this answer is useful" up arrow.